# Worauf bezieht sich "es" in "es bleibt noch viel zu..."?

Tags: gender, pronoun, phrase-request

Warum finde ich das Wort "Lippen" mit dem Pronomen "es"? Ist *Lippen* hier nicht feminin und Plural?

Der Kontext ist das Gedicht *"Es bleibt noch"* von Rose Ausländer. Dort heißt es in der letzten Strophe:

> Lippen
>   ja
>   **es** bleibt noch
>   viel zu sagen

Ich möchte wissen, warum hier das Pronomen "es" ist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a poem: poets are not exactly known as sticklers for grammar. There is not a single full sentence in this poem. They way I understand it "Es" does not refer to lips. It's a generic "it" (as in, e.g. "it remains to be seen" or "it will rain tomorrow").

The last two lines are to be read together:

> es bleibt noch / viel zu sagen (it remains / much to be said)